# CSV write stream - split into multiple files and combine in one archive (e. g. zip)

Tags: node.js, typescript, csv

I have an application that processes larger amounts of data (about two million records) and returns a CSV file. Our processing pipeline is stream based. Current flow is that a stream of objects gets stringified and uploaded to s3:

DATA READ STREAM > CSV STRINGIFIER (this part I need to change) > S3 UPLOAD

A new requirement is that one CSV file can only contain N rows. Therefore I am trying to come up with a file splitter that produces multiple csv files and returns an archive to be uploaded – all in a stream. I need to return one write stream / async generator.

Below is what I have so far. I am struggling with: How to produce a zip that contains my csv files. I have looked at the archiver module, but it seams you can only add streams or buffers... however in my case I would need to add a file line by line.

```js
export const makeCsvStreamWrite = (header: Record<string, string>, rowLimit = 1000) =>
  async function* (input: AsyncIterable<Record<string, string | number>>) {
    let fileCounter = 1;
    let rowCounter = 0;
    let headerWritten = false;

    const archive = archiver("zip", {
      zlib: { level: 9 }, // Sets the compression level.
    });

    const stringifier = stringify();
    const stringifiedInput = Readable.from(input).pipe(stringifier);

    for await (const row of stringifiedInput) {
      rowCounter++;

      if (!headerWritten) {
        yield stringifySync([header]);
        headerWritten = false;
      }

      yield row;

      if (rowCounter >= rowLimit) {
        // Now I would like to start a new file
        
        rowCounter = 0;
        fileCounter++;
        headerWritten = false;
      }
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have looked at the archiver module, but it seems you can only add streams or buffers... however in my case I would need to add a file line by line.

The following function takes as arguments an asynchronous iterator, an [archive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver) and a maximal number of lines. It consumes the iterator and writes the transformed lines into individual file streams (with at most N lines each). All file streams are added to the archive as readable streams.

```js
async function Splitter(input, archive, N) {
  var file;
  var fileCount = 0;
  for await (var line of input) {
    if (!file) {
      file = new stream.PassThrough();
      archive.append(file, { name: "file" + ++fileCount });
      lines = 0;
    }
    /* Transform line as needed. */
    file.write(line);
    if (++lines === N) {
      file.end();
      file = undefined;
    }
  }
  if (file) file.end();
}
```

You can pipe the `archive` to a writable stream (for example, an S3 upload) *before* calling the `Splitter` function:

```js
archive.pipe(writableStream);
await Splitter(input, archive, N);
archive.finalize();
```

Comment: Thank you. But with this direction, I would loose all the streaming benefits wouldn't I? I can't pipe the archive that the function returns into the my stream upload to s3. Instead I have to await the async function.

Comment: You can pipe the archive to S3 _before_ calling `Splitter`.

Comment: Mh, for me the uplaod never comes through.. did some research, looking at the issues it seems that archiver is not compatible with the aws sdk v3, since it uses an outdated readable stream implementation dating back to node 10. Nevertheless thank you for your help. It's much appreciated.

Comment: Quick note: There is a minor issue with the code you provided. At the very end, after iterating, please check if there is an open file and if so, close it. Otherwise the stream hangs forever.